# custom Ubuntu iso with a specific kernel version

Tags: server, kernel, iso

i was looking for a way to custom ubuntu iso with a specific kernel version

i have put all kernel deb to pool/extra. but i don't know how to tell installer to install a specific kernel version.

i search google for relative document , most of them are talking to preseed file

i notice there is a strinq about the kernel in the *.seed file, it looks like:

```
  # Use server kernel
d-i     base-installer/kernel/image     string linux-server
```

it said "Use server kernel", i dont quite understand what is really mean , how can it locale server kernel package , which version will it use . is "string linux-server" a format writing ?

we actually want to make it automatically to install our kernel version in the installation stage so we dont have to update kernel every time the when system installation completed

any one can guide me a way ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can choose the version of the kernel (but still limited to those provided by Ubuntu, e.g. 4.4 4.8 4.10 for 16.04) in the "Expert Mode" (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/InstallMethods#Expert_mode) of the installer. The choice window will appear during the "Installing the Base System" step.

(if I understand the question correctly)

Comment: thks for your reply ,  in the Expert mode , it said "press F6 " , it is not satisfy our requirement , we want  it follow our rule to step by step , without interrupt